# Apache: Virtual Host and .htacess for URL Rewriting not working

Tags: seo, apache, htaccess, url-rewriting, virtualhost

I have configured a virtual host in my local machine and every thing is working fine.
Now I want to use SEO friendly urls. To achieve this I have used the .htaccess file.

My virtual host configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/ypp"
    ServerName ypp.com
    ServerAlias www.ypp.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and my .htaccess file has:

```
AllowOverride All
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /ypp/ 
RewriteRule ^/browse$ /browse.php 
RewriteRule ^/browse/([a-z]+)$ /browse.php?cat=$1 
RewriteRule ^/browse/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$ /browse.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2
```

The above .htaccess setting is not working.
After that I modified my virtual host setting and it is working.
The new virtual host setting is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/browse$ /browse.php
    RewriteRule ^/browse/([a-z]+)$ /browse.php?cat=$1
    RewriteRule ^/browse/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$ /browse.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2
    ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
        DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/ypp"
    ServerName ypp.com
    ServerAlias www.ypp.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/ypp">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong in the .htacess file for url rewriting. I do not want to use the settings in virtual host, since for every change I have restart apache.

Comment: @parth: not a programming question. Voting to migrate to ServerFault.

Comment: is it really AllowOverride All RewriteEngine On or
  AllowOverride All (new line)
  RewriteEngine On

Comment: Yep for every change you restart apache but this way apache will never have to check *each* time the htaccess when someone will read a page. Htaccess files in your case are far less efficient than htaccess. Think about that when going in prod. environment

Answer (score 4):

You must put `AllowOverride All` in your `<Directory/>` section of the server configuration.

The only Apache configuration files that can allow options are the ones directly in the server (main file, virtualhost, etc.).

The .htaccess file can only **remove** override rights.

That is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/ypp"
    ServerName ypp.com
    ServerAlias www.ypp.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.localhost-access.log" combined
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/ypp">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and the .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /ypp/ 
RewriteRule ^/browse$ /browse.php 
RewriteRule ^/browse/([a-z]+)$ /browse.php?cat=$1 
RewriteRule ^/browse/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$ /browse.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2
```

Comment: You are generally correct, except I believe `mod_rewrite` only requires `AllowOverride FileInfo`, so you should set it to that in the vhost config instead of `All` unless you really need to allow all directives in .htaccess. It's best to follow the [principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).